# Assembly x86 32 bit/reverse and append string

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I want to reverse string in Assembly x-86. meaning - If I got "1234", I want to that my result will be "4321". I think to push each char to the stack, and the pop them. But I don't know to implement this.I need a buffer for this? (I can override the orginal string).

Comment: are you using binary for this? meaning 1234 = 10011010010? if yes then you can use the function RoR (rotate right) 16 times for 32bit notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work (assuming 32-bit mode, written using NASM syntax):

```
; finding string length:
mov ebx, mystr ; current position within the string
mov ecx, 0 ; current string length

l1:
mov al, [ebx] ; fetch a character from the string
cmp al, 0 ; is this string end?
je l2 ; yes, it is

inc ebx ; increment the position from where we'll read next character
inc ecx ; increment length
jmp l1 ; repeat

l2: ; ecx = string length

; reversing the string:
cmp ecx, 2 ; is the string too short?
jb l4 ; yes, it has 0 or 1 chars, we're done

mov ebx, mystr ; ebx points to the first char in the string
lea edx, [ebx+ecx-1] ; edx = ebx+ecx-1 - points to the last char in the string
shr ecx, 1 ; ecx = half the string length

l3:
mov al, [ebx]
xchg al, [edx]
mov [ebx], al ; [ebx] and [edx] swapped
inc ebx ; advance head pointer
dec edx ; advance tail pointer
loop l3 ; decrement ecx and if ecx isn't 0, repeat

l4:
;...

; string (NULL-terminated):
mystr db '1','2','3','4',0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one of the abstract data types (such as a stack or queue) but why bother?

Simply use two pointers, one at the start and one at the end, then swap what they point to. Increment the start pointer and decrement the end one then keep going until they meet or cross.

In the following code (pseudo-code since (1) this sounds a little like homework and (2) it's easily convertible to any procedural language), I'll assume C-style strings but you can adjust for other variants reasonably easily. Pseudocode such as the following would suffice, assuming that you have access to the value, `address of first character`:

```
set pstart to address of first character

# Locate last character
set pend to pstart
while [pend] is not null:
    pend = pend + 1
pend = pend - 1

# Continue until they cross
while pstart < pend:
    # Swap contents
    tmp = [pstart]
    [pstart] = [pend]
    [pend] = tmp

    # Move pointers
    pstart = pstart + 1
    pend = pend - 1
```

If you *really* want to use an ADT, a stack will suffice with the following logic:

```
# Push until reached end of string
set pchar to address of first character
while [pchar] is not null:
    push [pchar]
    pchar = pchar + 1

# Then pop the same way (but reverse order)
set pchar to address of first character
while [pchar] is not null:
    pop [pchar]
    pchar = pchar + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're tracking the original string, but I did something similar ages ago.  The easiest (but not speed optimal) way, assuming you're taking keyboard input, is to have a buffer, stosb into the buffer with the default direction flag, then after input is done, flip the direction flag, setup the registers and then lodsb...  Adapt as necessary depending on where your string is coming from.